# Apache Camel starts new asynchrounus route from current route

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, multicast

I am trying to do something like this

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("direct:a")
    // I want this route to stop here (reply with the response from "direct a"
    // then starts "direct:async" in new thread because it will take time 
    // (more that route timeout 
    .to("direct:async");
```

Comment: reply with the response to where?

Comment: to the application who called "direct:start" without waiting for body update from "direct:async"

Comment: Not sure. What you are asking. Apache camel works in a asynchronous way ... It is like a pipeline. There is no return value.

Comment: @pvpkiran. That is not true. Whether it works asynchronous or not is up to how you design your routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  can use the **wiretap**. You start your route from *direct:start*, then send a copy of the exchange  asynchronous with the *wireTap* (starts a new thread) and you route will continue with *direct:a*

```
from("direct:start").wireTap("direct:async").to("direct:a")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I have tried     from("direct:start").wireTap("direct:async").to("direct:a")            and it worked fine ,should I use the wireTrap instead of InOnly?

Comment: Your welcome, if my answer works for you, you can check it as ansered!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "should I use the wireTrap instead of InOnly" ? 

Camel will copy the original Exchange and set its Exchange Pattern to InOnly, as we want the tapped Exchange to be sent in a fire and forget style.